# Node.js - Q library, how can I access the value gotten in a previous then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am using Q in a Node.js application to implement promises and have something like this in which there is some promise chaining:

```
service.execute()
.then((result1) => {
  return service2.execute(result1);
})
.then((result2) => {
  //Here I need result1 and result2!!!
});
```

In the second then I need to use result1 from the previous then block but it isn't available. Is there a way to access it?

**NOTE:** There are similar questions but none of them solve the problem for Q library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain off of your inner promise:

```
service.execute().then((result1) => {
  return service2.execute(result1).then((result2) => {
      // Here I have access to both result1 and result2.
      // Result1 via the closure, Result2 as an argument.
  });
});
```

This is likely the best way to do it given that getting `result2` requires having `result1` already. If they didn't depend on each other like that, you could use `Promise.all`.